# Git plugin in Jenkins throws a NullPointerException, but can check out

Tags: git, jenkins

I've configured the Git plugin (2.3.2, with Git client 1.13.0) on our new Jenkins (1.580.2).

When I enter the Git URL, I get an ERROR link and an "irate Jenkins" with a stack trace (see below).

The job is able to check out and build, but it seems that the Stash Git hook is not working correctly (see second stacktrace).

Any hints to what I'm doing wrong?

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:795)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:875)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$6.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:249)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:53)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:745)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:875)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$6.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:249)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:53)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:745)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:875)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:648)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.service(Stapler.java:237)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:686)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1494)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:96)
    at hudson.plugins.greenballs.GreenBallFilter.doFilter(GreenBallFilter.java:58)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:99)
    at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:198)
    at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:176)
    at net.bull.javamelody.PluginMonitoringFilter.doFilter(PluginMonitoringFilter.java:85)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.plugins.monitoring.HudsonMonitoringFilter.doFilter(HudsonMonitoringFilter.java:99)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:99)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:88)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1482)
    at hudson.security.csrf.CrumbFilter.doFilter(CrumbFilter.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1482)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:84)
    at hudson.security.UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.doFilter(UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.java:51)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at jenkins.security.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:117)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at org.acegisecurity.providers.anonymous.AnonymousProcessingFilter.doFilter(AnonymousProcessingFilter.java:125)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at org.acegisecurity.ui.rememberme.RememberMeProcessingFilter.doFilter(RememberMeProcessingFilter.java:142)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at org.acegisecurity.ui.AbstractProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractProcessingFilter.java:271)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at jenkins.security.BasicHeaderProcessor.doFilter(BasicHeaderProcessor.java:86)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at org.acegisecurity.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:249)
    at hudson.security.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.java:67)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:76)
    at hudson.security.HudsonFilter.doFilter(HudsonFilter.java:164)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1482)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.compression.CompressionFilter.doFilter(CompressionFilter.java:46)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1482)
    at hudson.util.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1474)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:499)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:533)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1086)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:428)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1020)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:370)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:489)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:949)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1011)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:644)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:668)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:52)
    at winstone.BoundedExecutorService$1.run(BoundedExecutorService.java:77)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at hudson.FilePath.<init>(FilePath.java:242)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.Git.in(Git.java:36)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitAPI.<init>(GitAPI.java:47)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.Git$1.invoke(Git.java:63)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.Git$1.invoke(Git.java:54)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.Git.getClient(Git.java:66)
    at hudson.plugins.git.UserRemoteConfig$DescriptorImpl.doCheckUrl(UserRemoteConfig.java:149)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1869.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function$InstanceFunction.invoke(Function.java:298)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvoke(Function.java:161)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvokeAndServeResponse(Function.java:96)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$1.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:121)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:53)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:745)
    ... 72 more


Started on Jan 19, 2015 1:02:48 PM
Using strategy: Default
[poll] Last Built Revision: Revision d153e4bcef9a0f56685cc47c89c6f3526d83ccd9 (origin/develop)
ERROR: Failed to record SCM polling for hudson.maven.MavenModuleSet@2ee6d4ab[foo]
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at hudson.FilePath.<init>(FilePath.java:242)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.Git.in(Git.java:36)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitAPI.<init>(GitAPI.java:47)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.Git$1.invoke(Git.java:63)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.Git$1.invoke(Git.java:54)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.Git.getClient(Git.java:66)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.createClient(GitSCM.java:637)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.compareRemoteRevisionWithImpl(GitSCM.java:564)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.compareRemoteRevisionWith(GitSCM.java:516)
    at hudson.scm.SCM.compareRemoteRevisionWith(SCM.java:384)
    at hudson.scm.SCM.poll(SCM.java:401)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject._poll(AbstractProject.java:1433)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.poll(AbstractProject.java:1336)
    at jenkins.triggers.SCMTriggerItem$SCMTriggerItems$Bridge.poll(SCMTriggerItem.java:119)
    at hudson.triggers.SCMTrigger$Runner.runPolling(SCMTrigger.java:515)
    at hudson.triggers.SCMTrigger$Runner.run(SCMTrigger.java:544)
    at hudson.util.SequentialExecutionQueue$QueueEntry.run(SequentialExecutionQueue.java:118)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Apparently, I must specify a path to include ("Polling ignores commits in certains paths"). If I specify a path in the repo, even though it contains only one project to build, the polling works.

Comment: Do you mean that you didn't have any branches specified in the "branches to build" field? Did adding some solve your problem?

Comment: Hi Kyle! No, we always have a branch in the configuration. I haven't solved the problem yet, perhaps a next Jenkins version will fix it?

Comment: Try linking to this question on the Jenkins IRC; they helped me solve a problem that looked similar. In my case, Jenkins had misconfigured the ssh key profile, which was fixed by going to the ssh settings panel and changing the settings appropriately.

Comment: I am running into this same problem.  I am configuring Jenkins to Stash over unencrypted HTTP, no SSH.  I refer to a specific branch.   I set a poll SCM for 10 minutes.  It will run fine for a while, then it happens again.  I bounce Jenkins and it is fine again for a couple hours.  I am willing to put in a bounty if you post an answer or even share helpful information.

Comment: @maple_shaft If you're using HTTP without SSH, then it's *probably* a different issue; does your stacktrace actually match eerriicc's?. I recommend either opening a new question and/or (as I recommended to eerriicc) asking about your issue on the Jenkins IRC.

Comment: @KyleStrand Hi, I posted roughly my problem on the IRC.  I will work on posting my own question on SO later.

Comment: FWIW, I changed my Branch Specifier from `*/master` to `refs/heads/*` and this happened. I reverted, then specified the branch names to build separately via regex (e.g., `*/dev-*`), and it went away. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯